# collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld' when executing make install

Tags: oracle, postgresql, gcc, ora2pg, orafce

I am migrating an Oracle Database to Postgres and I wanted to install orafce which is a module that contains some useful function which can help with the porting.

I tried to execute the command "make install" but I got this error "collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'"

gcc version : 4.8.5
binutils version : 2.25.1

I didn't find anything that corresponds to my situation anywhere.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have `ld` installed?

Comment: Is there a command to know for sure? because I found an 'ld' link in /usr/bin

Comment: Type `ld` into your shell and see what happens.

Comment: I've got permission denied when I typed it. I followed the link and found `ld.bfd` in /usr/bin.
I executed ls -l and this is what I got `----------. 1 root root 873960 Nov 21  2017 ld.bfd`

Comment: Seems like your system is somewhat broken. Which operating system are you using anyway?

Comment: I'm using linux (RedHat RHEL 7.4)

Answer (score 2):

Your installation of `binutils` is broken.

Reinstall it with

```
yum reinstall binutils
```

You should figure out who changed the permissions. Maybe they did more damage than that.